# IntelliJ - Creating an application for Android Wear

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, sdk

I want to create an application for Android Wear. In IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1, I go to File -> New -> Project and select Android project. I check only the "Wear" box and make the minimum SDK "N: Android API 23, N preview (Preview)".

I create an Android Wear emulator that runs "Android N, API 23".

When I run the MainActivity I get the following error:

```
Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

When I go to File -> Project Settings, under "Project" the Project SDK is "Android API 23, N preview Platform". Under "Modules" the app Module SDK and the WearApplicationTest Module are both "Project SDK (Android API 23, N preview Platform)".

Under Platform Settings -> SDKs I have the Java 1.8 SDK, with the correct JDK home path "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home". I also have the Java 1.7 SDK with the correct JDK home path "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home".

Additionally I have the "Android API 23, N preview Platform" SDK which has a build target of "Android API 23, N preview (Preview)" and Java SDK of 1.8. I also have the "Android API 24 Platform" SDK with a build target of "Android API 24" and Java SDK of 1.8. And lastly I have the "Android API 23 Platform" SDK with the build target of "Android API 23" and Java SDK of 1.7.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "****.wearapplicationtest"
        minSdkVersion 'N'
        targetSdkVersion 'N'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your android sdks and tools to latest version using SDK Manager and changing your references of "N" to 24 in your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "****.wearapplicationtest"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.2.1'
}
```

Comment: All of my android sdks and tools are updated. When I change something in the build.gradle, even if I change it back, gradle project sync is unable to complete and I get the following error: `Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: /Users/*****/Android/bin/java`. This location is not the location I have specified in the java 1.8 SDK home path in Project Structe -> Platform Settings -> SDKs. Also, if I move the java home folder to the location it says it tried, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please help sir/ma'am!

Comment: then fix the location in that same SDKs screen.  What probably happened is that your computer updated to the latest java (currently 102) and the path to the JDK changed and intellij needs to know the new location. This can be done by clicking the ... button and fixing the path.  When it is correct the classpath pane just below will fill up with lots of jars contained in the jdk!  HTHS!